# Tag management: vitamins and micronutrients

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

"vitamins" and "micronutrients" tags were two separate tags before, and now Micronutrients redirects to Vitamins. This is erroneous because micronutrients are not only vitamins, there are also minerals and antioxidants. In other words they're not synonims, one is subset of the other.

I propose two answers and let's see which one gets more votes: make vitamins redirect to micronutrients and keep two separate tags. In my opinion the "two separate tags" is the best.

Comment: I’m the one that created the synonym. I take your point about the subset relationship and would be happy to turn the direction around. I don’t think people tend to distinguish these in common usage, and since we agree that all vitamins are micronutrients, I don’t see much point in having two tags.

Answer (score 3):

"Vitamins" should redirect to "micronutrients" instead of the current situation where "micronutrients" redirects to "vitamins".

NOTE: I've read comments and I think it's good thing not having too many tags. This becomes my favourite solution. I can't upvote my own answers. Please consider this is my favourite option, so +1 :)

Comment: There hasn’t been a lot of voting here, but I went ahead and swapped [tag:vitamins] and [tag:micronutrients] in accordance with this answer since it’s the highest voted and the OP agrees (as do I ). If others come weigh in and we come to a different conclusion, it can be changed. Thank you for bringing this to our attention.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the [vitamins](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vitamins) tag. At the time  was thinking "vitamins" is a subset of the set "micronutrients." I also think "trace elements" (meaning Zinc, Manganese, Boron, Copper, Molybdenum, and Nickel, needed in very small amounts but toxic in larger amounts) is a subset of "micronutrients".

"Minerals" (in my mind - and I may be out of synch here) are needed in larger quantities (Sodium, Calcium, Potassium, Magnesium, Phosphorous, Chlorine, and Sulphur) and are not a subset of the "micronutrients".

That makes sense to me. As for having two tags, can't someone pick "micronutrients" then specify which? There is something I am missing bout tags.

Comment: Yep, I think making everything converge to micronutrients is the best choice. Everything except "trace elements" because -but I'm not sure, please correct me if I'm wrong- also pesticide residues and heavy metals are trace elements and I wouldn't call them micronutrients.

Comment: @Attilio - Hmm, I mercury, lead and arsenic are heavy metal, right? But they aren't needed by the body. The trace elements I’m thinking of are Zinc, Manganese, Boron, Copper, Molybdenum, and Nickel, which are needed in microquantities, but toxic in larger doses, as are heavy metals.

Comment: `can't someone pick "micronutrients" then specify which?`: Practically, I’m not sure how to make them do that. If we have both the parent and the daughter tags, it seems like they will just end up being used inconsistently (i.e. some with only the parent, some with one or other daughter, some with both). Anyway, sorry to have messed up your tag creation with that mapping; clearly my mistake!

Comment: @Susan - no, not at all. I still don't understand fully how tags work. That's why, while I may be defining some, I'm not dealing with synonyms. It might be me who messed up your system.

Comment: In the same way, shouldn't we then also have "Macronutrients", with fat/carbs/proteins redirecting there?

Comment: @anongoodnurse yes yes, maybe I was not clear enough. apparently ( http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0946672X06001283 ) there are good trace elements, like zinc, copper, etc. and bad trace elements, like lead, and trace elements that are good or bad according to the quantity. for this ambiguity I wouldn't make "trace elements" redirect to micronutrients. but-anyway- I don't think it's THAT important this issue about "trace elements".

Answer (score -3):

"vitamins" and "micronutrients" should be two different tags.

Comment: In which case we should also have a tag `minerals`, and all questions with either `vitamin` or `mineral` should also be tagged `micronutrient`? That seems difficult to get people to comply with. If there are going to be two tags, `vitamins` and `minerals` seems to make more sense. But, then we have to do *something* with it when people try `micronutrient`, and since (as you point out), it shouldn’t re-direct to either of the others.....subset relationships are confusing with tags. This is why I vote for subsuming them both under `micronutrients`.